# Load html with variables after Twig is rendered

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twig

I am currently using Twig. I render all the views which works like a charm but there is one problem:
I am using jQuery to load a dialog when I click a button. It loads a new html file into my website, but when I try to use Twig's variables (like `{{ user.name }}`), it just outputs it as a string (which is logic to me while Twig is already rendered).

Now is my question: is it possible to render Twig again after the dialog is loaded? So variables will be outputted as their value?

I hope I have made my problem clear. If not: just ask for anything! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `display()`? According to the docs:

> The display() method is a shortcut to output the template directly.

So, in your controller, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html');
$htmlString = $template->display(array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));
```

And then pass the `$htmlString` back to the view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The point is that I want something to be rendered AFTER the template is rendered. I ain't using a controller for html loaded loaded with jQuery.

Comment: You need to boot `twig` in your ajax call if you want to use it functions

Comment: Thanks both. I just had to assign the url from my ajax call to my router and then I was able to render my Twig template with the variables.